# Как вернуть остаток от деления, не используя %?

Tags: php, деление

Например, есть некая функция

```
function remainder($a, $b)
{
    return $a % $b;
}
echo remainder(9,4); //1
```

Какие есть возможные способы вернуть остаток от деления(не обязательно от 9 на 4), и сколько этих способов существует вообще?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если стоит задача зачем-то избежать использования оператора %, но можно использовать другие операторы/функции, то можно подойти к решению, исходя непосредственно из определения остатка:

Деление с остатком a на b означает нахождение таких целых чисел q и r, что выполняется равенство:
    a = b * q + r
где r - остаток (определения остальных чисел опустим).

Тогда r = a - b*q или на php:

```
<?
function remainder($a, $b)
{
    return $a - ((int)($a/$b))*$b;
// или для PHP 7
//  return $a - intdiv($a,$b)*$b;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

По-моему, один из самых простых способов -- отнимать в цикле делитель от делимого до тех пор, пока остаток от деления не станет меньше делителя. Для чисел 9 и 4, например:

```
1-я итерация: 9-4 = 5, 5 > 4
2-я итерация: 5-4 = 1, 1 < 4
```

Получили остаток от деления. Не знаток php, но, думаю, в коде будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
function remainder($a, $b)
{
    while ($a >= $b)
        $a -= $b;

    return $a;
}
echo remainder(9,4);// 1
echo remainder(12,3); // 0
echo remainder(19,5); // 4
```